# Javascript to show hidden div overlay with close button on clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, overlay

I am after a little help - I'm not a great programmer, and can usually find the answers to my questions with googling, but not this time!

I am trying to produce a specific effect on a webpage, and am struggling to find some basic JS I can modify/tweak to do what I need.

I am going to put a panel of 10 images, in two rows of five, across a webpage. Each image will have a 'Name' above it, and a 'Job Title' below it. When the image is clicked on, I'd like the (relevant) hidden div to display, over the top of all the images - i.e. with the top left corner matching the top left corner of the first image. The div will be a pre-set width.

In the top corner of each div I want a simple close button.

So, what I am trying to produce is code that's scalable - i.e. in theory it shouldn't matter how many images there are as long as I get the structure right, when you click on the image, it 'shows' the correct hidden div.

We already load jQuery on to the webpage, so using that would be no problem.

Any advice/links to snippets/pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to display a div over all images when an image is clicked..? what about the content in those divs..? are they all the same..? What is the html structure and css you currently have for those images..?

Comment: @TJ The structure can be modified to suit - what I'm envisaging is something along the lines of
<div id='image1'><img /><div id='hidden1'>Content</div></div>
<div id='image2'><img /><div id='hidden2'>Content</div></div>
<div id='image3'><img /><div id='hidden3'>Content</div></div>
<div id='image4'><img /><div id='hidden4'>Content</div></div>
Where the images are displayed, and the hidden divs are kept hidden until the image is clicked on. The hidden divs would contain a close button each.

Comment: In addition to @Gino Pane's answer, have a look at http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks @RobSchmuecker - that actually looks a little complicated for what I need. My overlay doesn't need the bells and whistles of being movable/interactive. However, that's a really helpful link as I'm sure I can make that work if need be.

Comment: @JamesDavies, plainOverlay is not for dynamic overlays only, You can set up Your own there, that's why I've suggested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simply achieved with jQuery and jQueryUI.

For brevity I have only included 5 images here http://jsfiddle.net/8kefF/2/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="clickThisPicture" data-content-id="1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="clickThisPicture" data-content-id="2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="clickThisPicture" data-content-id="3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="clickThisPicture" data-content-id="4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="clickThisPicture" data-content-id="5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hiddenContent" data-content-id="1">Hidden content 1</div>
<div class="hiddenContent" data-content-id="2">Hidden content 2</div>
<div class="hiddenContent" data-content-id="3">Hidden content 3</div>
<div class="hiddenContent" data-content-id="4">Hidden content 4</div>
<div class="hiddenContent" data-content-id="5">Hidden content 5</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenContent {
    display:none;
}
.clickThisPicture {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickThisPicture').on('click', function (event) {
        var contentId = $(this).data('content-id');
        $(".hiddenContent[data-content-id='" + contentId + "']").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:  I updated the code to hide the default `close` button so as to destroy the element each time as the OP asked for scalability so having potentially 100's/1000's of extra elements in the DOM would lead to memory issues. eventually.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks @RobSchmuecker, I'll take that fiddle and tweak it with my own formatting.

Comment: I've started having a play with this, and have implemented it on this testing page:
http://www.stormforce.biz/test-pages/test-interns.html
The issue I've run into now is styling the dialogue box, and positioning it so it starts at the top left hand corner of my first image (i.e. I want it to cover all of the images).
I'm assuming this is set in the JavaScript somewhere - I've called both jQuery and the jQuery UI. How do I change the look and feel of the box?

Comment: Hi James, have a  look at the `position` parameter of the "options" you pass to the dialog.  http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position
It takes a coordinate pair so you'll have to make sure that you get the top-left coordinates of your first image such as `$('.clickThisPicture:first').position();` or similar.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this position, and the syntax of putting it into the code.
If I put the word position in below the other parameters (such as draggable etc) it stops anything from happening (although I might be getting that wrong!). I've tried putting the code in to get the position of the first .clickThisPicture, and use that to set the position of the dialogue in a new line, but again it doesn't work. 
If you get five minutes today to take a look, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi James, I see on your test page you aren't getting a copy of jQuery UI loaded which can make a dialog and hence it's giving error.  I saw you were battling yesterday with the position but you were forgetting the comma and hence all the things behind it weren't working! Here's some other test code to help do what you need http://jsfiddle.net/dFZ9p/2/

Comment: you're a genius, thank you so much. Seriously helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bugging. On the fiddles, I can move the position - it sometimes has unexpected results, but I can change it! I've tried it relative to the first picture, and I've experimented with having it relative to the bounding div (with a class), and another div (with an ID). All of these methods seem to work on the fiddles, but when I put it on my page, it sticks to the top of the screen and I can't work out why!
Everything apart from the position is behaving as expected. Any tips as to where my page issue might be? http://www.stormforce.biz/test-pages/test-interns.html

Comment: Interestingly, I have a second test page, which shows the panel in a completely different position still: http://www.stormforce.biz/test-pages/test-page-2.html
I've removed a landing form created from an outside API - it seemed to be causing some jQuery conflict.

Comment: I got the `left` and `top` positions wrong, have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/dFZ9p/4/ and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, I was unable to get it to go in the correct place for the top left corner of the image, so in the end went for a modal centre in the page. You can see it in all it's glory here - http://www.stormforce.biz/information-pages/working-with-stormforce/internship.html#.U2uAEdyR-hM - many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this jQuery plugin will help You: [plainOverlay](http://anseki.github.io/jquery-plainoverlay/)