# How to pass values in a modal popup using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In a table I display several links whose value (user id) is extracted from a database. By clicking on the link appears a modal pop up in which I would like to pass the selected value.

Here is the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Id</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    include ‘db_connection.php’;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[userID]?></td>
    <td>
        <div id='basic-modal'>
            <a href="?id=<?php echo $row[userID]?>"  class='basic'>Show</a>
        </div>
     </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

If I click on the link Show appears the  modal pop up:

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET[‘userID’])){
            $userID = $_GET[‘userID’];
            echo ‘UsuerID: ‘ .$userID;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is the script I used

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Since I have little familiarity with the jQuery framework I would like to ask you how can I pass the selected value within the modal and then use it.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question a few minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493170/javascript-to-show-hidden-div-overlay-with-close-button-on-clicks/23494003  You output your HTML accordingly or change the JS accordingly.

Comment: can u give me full code.. i also want this.. plzz

Answer (score 1):

jquery allows you to use the .data() attribute

```
    <div id='basic-modal'>
        <a href="?id=<?php echo $row[userID]?>"  data-mydata="<?php echo $row[userID]?>" class='basic'>Show</a>
    </div>
```

and then u can retrieve data from 'data-mydata' attribute:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content')
              .text($(this).data('mydata'))
               .modal();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Bartlomiej,
thank you for your answer. Now I can pass the value thanks to your suggestion.
The question that I ask myself now is how to pass this value in a variable $ userID = ' '; which I create inside the div basic-modal-content.

Comment: u can rid of  this php code, instead you should do 
$('#basic-modal-content')
              .text('UserID: ' + $(this).data('mydata')).modal()

Comment: Hi Bartlomiej,
perhaps I did not explain well what I want to achieve.
I would like to pass the value in a SELECT through a variable named 
$userId as shown below in order to show the user data.

    
<div id="basic-modal-content>
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $userId";
          $res = mysql_query($sql);
          $ row = mysql_fetch_array($res);       
    ?>
  </div>